# Does EventSource consume resource of browser?

Tags: javascript, server-sent-events, eventsource

I coded some simple SSE over HTTP/2. It worked fine as my expectation. It carried some data from the server to the client periodically.

But when I saw the dev-console of the browser, I found some scary thing,

[Picture of Resource is increasing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nDBX.png)

As time goes, the amount of resources is increasing. (I think it's due to data stream of SSE).

Question:

- Is it normal?
- How to clear consumed SSE streams? needless?

Here is a code;

```js
// Client
#listenSSE () {
  this.#sse = new EventSource('/_SSE/' + this.clientUID)
  this.#sse.onmessage = (event) => {
    const parsed = JSON.parse(event.data)
    console.log(parsed) // doing some job with SSE event.
  }
  this.#sse.onerror = (error) => {
    console.error('SSE error', error)
    this.#sse.close()
    this.#sse = null
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not "browser resources" (whatever it means) but the amount of uncompressed data transferred over the wire. And it seems totally legit that it grows as you get more and more data from the event source.

Comment: Thanks. I understand now.